# fullcalendar-rightclick.js is not working in fullcalendar.js latest version (3)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar-3

Fullcalendar-rightclick.js is not working in the latest version of fullcalendar.js
showing the following error

```
that.getHitSpan is not a function
```

Comment: https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-rightclick/blob/master/README.md